# Как лучше задать константные поля у функции-конструктора?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Как лучше всего задать константы у функции конструктора,чтобы их значения лежали в прототипе,тоесть,если я создам несколько объектов,то у всех этих объектов будут константы,которые найдутся только у одного родителя

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function Foo() {}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'BAR', { value: 42 });

const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.BAR);
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype, 'BAR'));
```

Почему используется `defineProperty` - потому что этот статический метод по-умолчанию устанавливает свойство как неизменяемое, неперечислимое и константное (`{ configurable: false, enumerable: false, writable: false }`).
То есть, попытки изменить константу в прототипе (или ее дескриптор) - не будут иметь эффекта.

Comment: Ну а сахарным `class`, сделать такое (по-моему) нельзя.